# How to generate an event after a HAPI Rest API Call execution?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are analyzing the implementation of HAPI as a method of FHIR-enabling a legacy information system.
We need to execute some other tasks after a REST API call is consumed in HAPI, for example notify a third party or execute a SQL SP.

Have you had similar experiences?
How have you tackled such requests?

Thanks a lot!

Nicolas E.